# How to append a hash to another hash where these hashes are value of a key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The final output would be as follows in a jsonb column in postgres column name `extras`

```
{“notes”: {“timestamp”: 1620742796, “prev_notes”: “someTest”, “new_notes”: “someText”},
        {“timestamp”: 1620742652, “prev_notes”: “someText”, “new_notes”: “AllGood”}
}
```

Following is the initial state in DB

```
{“notes”: {“timestamp”: 1620742796, “prev_notes”: “someTest”, “new_notes”: “someText”}
```

On rails console

```
stud = Student
stud.extras["notes"] = <gives current  state>
```

In my ruby on rails code, I build an obj

```
obj = {“timestamp”: 1620742652, “prev_notes”: “someText”, “new_notes”: “AllGood”}
```

Now I want to append above obj to value of the key "notes". I tried append, push, reverseMerge!, << . Nothing worked.

Comment: You can't have `{“notes”: {}, {}}`, that's not valid Ruby code. Shouldn't it be an array of hashes? `{“notes”: [{..}, {..}], ..}`

Comment: Seems like `"notes"` should be an array in either case. The plural form already indicates this.

Comment: Can you please fix the data examples so that they are valid Ruby?  Also please add your code that is not working, showing its actual output or the error you get, and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extra[:notes].merge(obj)
```

you can do this to merge it into one hash or you can convert notes into array and then save an array of hashes.

This is not a valid syntax:

```
{notes: {}, {}}
```

but this is valid:

```
{notes: [{}, {}]}
```